# How to put a button in listview,where the listview have values from database?

Tags: android, android-listview

There are so many questions and answers regarding this topic,but still I couldn't understand them.I'm learning android now,so please excuse me for this simple question.
I have listview where I load the values from database,now I need to delete those values in the listview by using button in the listview.

This is how I get data from database.

```
 private void loaddata() {
        db = helper.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DBhelper.TABLE1, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this,
                R.layout.row,
                c,
                new String[]{DBhelper.Name},
                new int[]{R.id.lblreload});
        rldlist.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

This is my row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">



    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblreload"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textColor="@color/abc_input_method_navigation_guard"

        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/lol"
        android:padding="10dp" />




</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You need to create a custom adapter and layout for the listview Check this: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Populating-a-ListView-with-a-CursorAdapter

Comment: updated my first comment, check the link

Comment: @xyz are you saying you already initialize adapter you want how to put a button in list view which will delete that row ?

Comment: Actually I didn't get your question,My fetch method is there using cursor adaptor,I need to put button in that listview ,that button need to delete that row.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly , you need to put that button for each row in your custom adapter :

YourAdapterClass.java :

public View getView()- >

```
delRow.setTag(position);
        delRow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    //do something here perhaps open the db like
                    source.open();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                source.deleteContact(tempList.get(position)); //del from db
                mObjectList.remove(((int) v.getTag()));//remove row
                YourAdapterClass.this.notifyDataSetChanged(); //let the adapter know.
```

**Explanation** :

> mObjectList is actually the array you're passing for each element
>   (Item1,Item2) ; tempList is actually a clone of that list because if
>   you delete the original it would destroy your actual list and make
>   chaotic changes in your listview or whatever you have.